# Theorem numbering with sections with LNCS

Tags: numbering, theorems, lncs

I'm using the file `llncs.cls`, downloadable [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs/conference-proceedings-guidelines) under "LaTeX2e Proceedings Templates (zip)".

I want to number theorems according to its section, for example Theorem 1.1, Theorem 1.2.

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]  

\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{thm}
abc
\end{thm}
\begin{thm}
def
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

When I do this, what appears instead is Theorem 11 and Theorem 12.

How can I add back the dots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `llncs` class needs the `envcountsect` option in order to provide the usual behaviour expected from `\newtheorem`, in addition, `llncs` uses `\spnewtheorem` rather than `\newtheorem`.

```
\documentclass[envcountsect,runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

\spnewtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]{\bfseries}{\itshape}

\begin{document}
\section{Section foo}
\begin{thm}
abc
\end{thm}
\begin{thm}
def
\end{thm}


\section{Section  foobar}
\begin{thm}
abc
\end{thm}
\begin{thm}
def
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Theorem in LLNCS should be defined with `\spnewtheorem`: `\spnewtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]{\bfseries}{\itshape}`